# Complexity asymptotic relation (theta, Big O, little o, Big Omega, little omega) between functions

Tags: aggregate-functions, complexity-theory, relation

Let's define:

```
Tower(1) of n is: n.
Tower(2) of n is: n^n (= power(n,n)). 
Tower(10) of n is: n^n^n^n^n^n^n^n^n^n.
```

And also given two functions:

```
f(n) = [Tower(logn n) of n] = n^n^n^n^n^n^....^n (= log n times "height of tower").
g(n) = [Tower(n) of log n] = log(n)^log(n)^....^log(n) (= n times "height of tower").
```

Three questions:

1. How are functions f(n)/g(n) related each other asymptotically (n-->infinity),
   in terms of: theta, Big O, little o, Big Omega, little omega ?
   Please describe exact way of solution and not only eventual result.
2. Does base of log (i.e.: 0.5, 2, 10, log n, or n) effect the result ?
   If no - why ? 
   If yes - how ?
3. I'd like to know whether in any real (even if hypotetic) application there complexity performance looks similar to f(n) or g(n) above. Please give case description - if such exist.

P.S.
I tried to substitute: log n = a, therefore: n = 2^a or 10^a.
And got confused of counting height of received "towers".

Answer (score 0):

I won't provide you a solution, because you have to work on your homework, but maybe there are other people interested about some hints.

1) **Mathematics**:

```
log(a^x) = x*log(a)
```

- this will humanize your problem

2) **Mathematics**:

```
logx(y) = log2(y) / log2(x) = log10(y) / log10(x)
```

- of course: if `x` is constant => `log2(x)` and `log10(x)` are constants

3) `recursive` + stop condition